# Query mesh for its interpolated light probe density

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are working on AI for our game, and currently the detection system. How can I read the lightprobe interpolation data off a mesh? If in shadow it will take longer time and closer distances for the AI to detect the player

edit: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LightProbes.GetInterpolatedProbe.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the best way is to use `GetInterpolatedProbe`

You call it like

```
SphericalHarmonicsL2 probe;
LightProbes.GetInterpolatedProbe(Target.position, renderer, out probe);
```

Make sure  the position is not inside the mesh since realtime shadows will effect the result

Then you can query the SphericalHarmonicsL2 doing

```
Vector3[] directions = {
            new Vector3(0, -1, 0.0f)
};  
var colors = new Color[1];
probe.Evaluate(directions, colors);
```

In above example you will get the color at the point from the upward direction. Above example will create garbage, make sure to re use arrays in real example